# Making BestNormalize to recognize different factor levels for better data transformation

Tags: r, r-markdown, normalization, data-transform

I'm using bestNormalize package to transform a variable with 5 factor levels (Groups). I use the following code to transform my data and see histograms and normality test results for the transformed data(nooutliers is my dataset, totalscore is my dependent variable, and Grade is a factor with 5 factor levels):

```
(BNobjectall <- bestNormalize(nooutliers$totalscore))
nooutliers$transformed <- predict(BNobjectall)
ggplot(nooutliers,aes(x=transformed, fill= Grade))+geom_histogram(binwidth=3)+facet_grid(~Grade)+theme_bw()


nooutliers %>%
  summarise(statistic = shapiro.test(transformed)$statistic,
           p.value = shapiro.test(transformed)$p.value)
```

My problem is that bestNormalize does not consider factor levels and finds the best transformation method as this variable was a single group. As a result, the transformed dependent variable values for one of my factor levels does not become normal. When I create a subset just for this factor level and apply the same code, I get the desired result. However, I don't know how I can apply this same transformation (with same values) to other factor levels.

Is there a way for bestNormalize to consider factor levels or to apply the same transformation with same values to different subsets?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your goal, but I can offer one thought.

`bestNormalize` requires "training" data, so you could consider training it on a single group, then applying it to the other groups using `predict`:

```
# Trains data on Grade 1
(BNobjectall <- bestNormalize(nooutliers$totalscore[nooutliers$Grade == 1]))

# Applies Grade 1 transform to all data points
nooutliers$transformed <- predict(BNobjectall)
```

If you are trying to ensure normality within each factor level, you will need to do the subsetting as you've done already and note that the normalization transformations may differ because the best normalizing transformation is different across groups. If you are trying to keep a consistent transformation across factor levels, then my advise would be to use a data-invariant transform such as a log or square-root transformation, or use the above approach.